# RSA / Asymmetric decryption in android

Tags: java, android, cryptography, rsa, pkcs#12

**Edit: Refactored the code based on comments, to validte Base64 as suggested**

I am trying to decode an RSA encrypted string on in Android, unsuccessfully.

```
// Retrieve the key from server
// Looks counter intuitive, but, the retrieval happens on trusted Intranet.
URL keyUrl = new URL(keyUri);
URLConnection keyConn = keyUrl.openConnection();
InputStream keyStream = keyConn.getInputStream();

// Create the keystore and load the key
KeyStore pkcsStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
pkcsStore.load(keyStream, "password".toCharArray());
KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("X509");
kmf.init(pkcsStore, "password".toCharArray());

// Retrieve the key from keystore
String clientKeyAlias = pkcsStore.aliases().nextElement();
Key clientKey = pkcsStore.getKey(clientKeyAlias, "password".toCharArray());
Log.d(TAG, String.format("Algorithm: %s Format: %s ", clientKey.getAlgorithm(), clientKey.getFormat()));

// Retrieve the public key from keystore
Certificate certificate = pkcsStore.getCertificate(clientKeyAlias);
PublicKey clientPublicKey = certificate.getPublicKey();

// Let's make sure the certificate/key stored in pkcsStore are valid
String plainText = "Stackoverflow is Amazing!";
Log.d(TAG,  String.format("Encrypting string '%s' to validate cert/key pair stored in pkcs store", plainText));
byte[] plainTextBytes = plainText.getBytes("UTF-8");

// Let's get the cipher instance
Cipher testCipher = Cipher.getInstance(clientKey.getAlgorithm());
testCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, clientPublicKey);

byte[] encryptedTextBytes = testCipher.doFinal(plainTextBytes);

testCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, clientKey);
byte[] decryptedTextBytes = testCipher.doFinal(encryptedTextBytes);

String decryptedPlainText = new String(decryptedTextBytes, "UTF-8");
Log.d(TAG, "Decrypted plainText " + decryptedPlainText);

// Retrieve the encrypted data from server
URL symUrl = new URL(symUri);
URLConnection connection = symUrl.openConnection();
int contentLength = connection.getContentLength();
Log.d(TAG, "Content length " + contentLength);

InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
// Validate the base64 string matches the data on server
String payLoad = br.readLine().trim(); // Trim the line in case echo there is a newline character
String base64StringOnServer = "nMdLvh+PDH1DimjQV0kTYU9E5tJA9VA2ADlcCQVkYwYZQWRFdT57bW4oDvlpGJ1KzJ/N3smyV5N7xlpNJo6HXans+cCImZI5MaZ9prEc3gUtIlwDWj80e0L+5YaRSIshXjPKvurjhwmppz+IAuh5Aq/c3ZdE2nbFn+L+2Ih91nsl6WV1diCEBw6pUIMtdPh8nXmQfp3ZbDKHt3VnSkoLLhPXYbYaTOaTuhAJZhszE5ejpB0sQ78d/1WbmPU1MnGCrUSOkM6s22fT3aTyzxo3IjmzXBWhz32tCbOBagmAsyaHlLHbQ2pQoxI9cR0hcZAc/IyEFKrVSJnFA03P/QzkhQ==";
Log.d(TAG, "Base64 as stored on the server: " + base64StringOnServer);
Log.d(TAG, "Base64 received from server: " + payLoad);
if (base64StringOnServer.equals(payLoad)) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Base64 string comparision passed");
}

// Get the byte array of payload
byte[] data = Base64.decode(payLoad, Base64.DEFAULT);

// Decipher the data
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(clientKey.getAlgorithm());
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, clientKey);
byte[] decryptedKeyBytes = cipher.doFinal(data);

// Validate the decrypted data
String decryptedKey = new String (decryptedKeyBytes, "UTF-8");
Log.d(TAG, "Decrypted Key: " + decryptedKey);
```

Here is the openssl command encrypting the data

```
openssl rsautl -encrypt -pubin -inkey rsakey.pub -in key.txt | base64 -w 0 > enc_base64.txt
```

I have decrypted payload by using private key at the source to validate as seen below.

```
cat key.base64 | base64 --decode |  openssl rsautl -decrypt -inkey rsakey.key
```

The code show above runs fine with no exceptions, but the decrypted payload is not valid.

Here is the excerpt from Logcat

```
// Base64 decode flag Base64.NO_WRAP
Algorithm: RSA Format: PKCS#8 
Encrypting string 'Stackoverflow is Amazing!' to validate cert/key pair stored in pkcs store
Decrypted plainText Stackoverflow is Amazing!
Content length 344
Base64 as stored on the server: nMdLvh+PDH1DimjQV0kTYU9E5tJA9VA2ADlcCQVkYwYZQWRFdT57bW4oDvlpGJ1KzJ/N3smyV5N7xlpNJo6HXans+cCImZI5MaZ9prEc3gUtIlwDWj80e0L+5YaRSIshXjPKvurjhwmppz+IAuh5Aq/c3ZdE2nbFn+L+2Ih91nsl6WV1diCEBw6pUIMtdPh8nXmQfp3ZbDKHt3VnSkoLLhPXYbYaTOaTuhAJZhszE5ejpB0sQ78d/1WbmPU1MnGCrUSOkM6s22fT3aTyzxo3IjmzXBWhz32tCbOBagmAsyaHlLHbQ2pQoxI9cR0hcZAc/IyEFKrVSJnFA03P/QzkhQ==
Base64 received from server: nMdLvh+PDH1DimjQV0kTYU9E5tJA9VA2ADlcCQVkYwYZQWRFdT57bW4oDvlpGJ1KzJ/N3smyV5N7xlpNJo6HXans+cCImZI5MaZ9prEc3gUtIlwDWj80e0L+5YaRSIshXjPKvurjhwmppz+IAuh5Aq/c3ZdE2nbFn+L+2Ih91nsl6WV1diCEBw6pUIMtdPh8nXmQfp3ZbDKHt3VnSkoLLhPXYbYaTOaTuhAJZhszE5ejpB0sQ78d/1WbmPU1MnGCrUSOkM6s22fT3aTyzxo3IjmzXBWhz32tCbOBagmAsyaHlLHbQ2pQoxI9cR0hcZAc/IyEFKrVSJnFA03P/QzkhQ==
Base64 string comparision passed
Decrypted Key: )|~`!��u��   zU.�縉)���#9�]�׶��Q����݌�Ő�A�f*(A�%U�/;�%2��j0I$dI*,'@�E�t@�P�=-C��VR�o06p�4op9�k�q  >�qq�>V�~Y���R�O���t2�S�֖E���&�rP�Q��L����2�;7��}�g�Wpٟ$P�N0�k�w��ň1����0�2��2�jҗ/�}r:*g"ոm���[����1234567812345678

// Base64 decode flag Base64.DEFAULT
Algorithm: RSA Format: PKCS#8 
Encrypting string 'Stackoverflow is Amazing!' to validate cert/key pair stored in pkcs store
Decrypted plainText Stackoverflow is Amazing!
Content length 344
Base64 as stored on the server: nMdLvh+PDH1DimjQV0kTYU9E5tJA9VA2ADlcCQVkYwYZQWRFdT57bW4oDvlpGJ1KzJ/N3smyV5N7xlpNJo6HXans+cCImZI5MaZ9prEc3gUtIlwDWj80e0L+5YaRSIshXjPKvurjhwmppz+IAuh5Aq/c3ZdE2nbFn+L+2Ih91nsl6WV1diCEBw6pUIMtdPh8nXmQfp3ZbDKHt3VnSkoLLhPXYbYaTOaTuhAJZhszE5ejpB0sQ78d/1WbmPU1MnGCrUSOkM6s22fT3aTyzxo3IjmzXBWhz32tCbOBagmAsyaHlLHbQ2pQoxI9cR0hcZAc/IyEFKrVSJnFA03P/QzkhQ==
Base64 received from server: nMdLvh+PDH1DimjQV0kTYU9E5tJA9VA2ADlcCQVkYwYZQWRFdT57bW4oDvlpGJ1KzJ/N3smyV5N7xlpNJo6HXans+cCImZI5MaZ9prEc3gUtIlwDWj80e0L+5YaRSIshXjPKvurjhwmppz+IAuh5Aq/c3ZdE2nbFn+L+2Ih91nsl6WV1diCEBw6pUIMtdPh8nXmQfp3ZbDKHt3VnSkoLLhPXYbYaTOaTuhAJZhszE5ejpB0sQ78d/1WbmPU1MnGCrUSOkM6s22fT3aTyzxo3IjmzXBWhz32tCbOBagmAsyaHlLHbQ2pQoxI9cR0hcZAc/IyEFKrVSJnFA03P/QzkhQ==
Base64 string comparision passed
Decrypted Key: )|~`!��u��   zU.�縉)���#9�]�׶��Q����݌�Ő�A�f*(A�%U�/;�%2��j0I$dI*,'@�E�t@�P�=-C��VR�o06p�4op9�k�q  >�qq�>V�~Y���R�O���t2�S�֖E���&�rP�Q��L����2�;7��}�g�Wpٟ$P�N0�k�w��ň1����0�2��2�jҗ/�}r:*g"ոm���[����1234567812345678
```

Comment: Have you tried both encryption and decryption using java?

Comment: Yes. I did use the public key from p12 container to encrypt a sample payload and decrypt using private key in Java, to make sure the certificate/key in p12 container are valid.

Comment: "...but the decrypted payload is not valid..." How do you know it's not valid?

Comment: A key is not a string, could you print your output in base 64 both in Java and on Android? And please show us an example of expected and actual output.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I have updated the question to answer your question. As you can see in the log (pasted at end of question), the key in question is valid RSA key. Further, I have made a sample encryption and decryption to validate that the key can be used to encipher/decipher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some missing details, but one bug that immediately jumps out is this:

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(clientKey.getAlgorithm());
```

`Key.getAlgorithm()` does not return enough information to be used as an argument to `Cipher.getInstance()`. It might return without throwing an exception, but the result will not be correct. Instead, always specify the full transformation string "*algorithm/mode/padding*" as the argument to `Cipher.getInstance()`. If you really encrypted the data as you indicated with `openssl` then this would be the correct line:

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
```

Comment: Could be, for instance the Bouncy Castle provider uses plain RSA as default, which will leave all the PKCS#1 v1.5 padding.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes We are using the asymmetric RSA key and only 'RSA' seems to be enough to initialize the cipher. I have updated question to answer the key's algorithm and encipher / decipher functions.

Comment: @fossil: You don't seem to be paying attention. Read my answer!

Comment: @JamesKPolk, I am so sorry. I believed I had tried that earlier, but I might have done something wrong. Your solution worked perfect. Thanks again.